# setNeedsDisplay not causing refresh drawRect

Tags: objective-c, nsview, drawrect

my project is some kind of a timing application for Mac OS X and I want to cause drawRect in TimeCircle to refresh myView. I´m aware that I asked a similar question before. But my problem is not solved yet and it is different from other topics which are similar.

What I have so far:

1. An NSObject Class TimeController which starts a timer and modifies some NSTextEdits on a per second base.
2. An NSView Class TimeCircle which is connected to a custom view which I want to draw a circle with a clock like hand representing the progress.
3. Imported TimeCircle.h in TimeController.m
4. An instance method **drawRectOutsideWrapper** which I send a message when the timer is running. [TimeCircle drawRectOutsideWrapper:(float) seconds]; this works.

drawRectOutsideWrapper is this:

```
- (void) drawRectOutsideWrapper:(float) seconds {
   liveAngle= seconds;
   [self->myTimeCircleView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

**drawRectOutsideWrapper** receives the message from **TimeController** correctly!

The problem is that **[self->myTimeCircleView setNeedsDisplay:YES];** doesn´t fire **drawRect**. It just does nothing.
For testing purposes I integrated a slider **makeLiveLine** which actually does the same thing and **drawRect** gets triggered correctly:

```
- (IBAction)makeLiveLine:(id)sender {
   liveAngle= [sender intValue];
   [self->myTimeCircleView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Any clues why one is doing the job and one doesn't?

Comment: I am not sure. Can you try to call IBAction method from drawRectOutsideWrapper(). Might be some problem of threads, if call this using selector in different thread.

Comment: mmh, I sent a message to - (IBAction)makeLiveLine:(id)sender and it does setNeedsDisplay:YES but without success. drawRect is still not triggered. This is annoying. It is perfect when using my slider.